# How do i use Lapsharp filter in ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I have been using the lapsharp filter in HandBrakeCLI i was wondering if ffmpeg has this filter or how to sharpen like lapsharp does. I use the lapsharp medium preset for downscaling 1080p to 720p, i like this filter because it doesn't apply sharpening in edges like the unsharp filter.

Answer (score 0):

By inspecting Lapsharp filter code in Handbrake, it is doing convolution using one of defined edge detectors and resulted values are then subtracted with original image pixel values, result of this operation is then multiplied with user supplied strength and added to original image pixel values, finally its is clipped to be in 0 - 255 range. This can be done with ffmpeg one convolution and multiple blend filters (first use grainextract mode of blend filter for convolution input and original input frame, and custom expression - to multiply values and add them to final output). If you give parameters you use the most with lapsharp of handbrake I could write filtergraph which should give exact results by using ffmpeg filters.

Comment: Could you make a filtergraph from this -- Sharpen (lapsharp) (y-strength=0.2:y-kernel=isolap:cb-strength=0.2:cb-kernel=isolap)